# Validar formulario primero con un archivo .js y luego enviar ese archivo al servidor mailchim con node express con otro archivo .js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy intentando validar un formulario con un archivo creado mío (main.js) y una vez que este validado, al darle al botón de enviar del formulario que envíe los datos a la base de datos de mailchim a través de otro archivo .js(app.js) creado con node y express y no se como hacerlo. Puedo o validarlo con javascript(main.js) o enviarlo sin validar con node(app.js) pero las dos cosas a la vez no se como.
Lo que me gustaría es que primero lo validase y luego enviarlo al servidor. No se si hay alguna forma de incorporar mi código de validación main.js en el archivo de node app.js o al revés.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
1)Index del formulario: contacta.html
2)Validación del formulario: main
3)Meter los datos del formulario en la base mailcimp: app
Muchas gracias.

Código servidor:

```
const express= require("express");
const bodyParser= require("body-parser");
const https = require("https");
const app= express();




app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
         extended: true
     }));
    
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/contacta.html");
})

app.post("/", function(req, res){

    const firstName = req.body.nombre;
    const lastName = req.body.apellidos;
    const email= req.body.correo;
    const telefono= req.body.telefono;

    const data = {
                members: [{
                    email_address: email,
                    status: "subscribed", // CREA EL OBJETO JSON DE LA APPI MAILCHIMP.COM
                    merge_fields: {
                        FNAME: firstName,
                        LNAME: lastName,
                        PHONE:telefono
                
                    }
                }]
            };
            const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data); // convierte un objeto o valor de JavaScript en una cadena de texto JSON,


            const url = "https://us17.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/9a8ca9505a";
            // endpoint api mailchimp
        
        
            const options = {
                method: "POST",
                auth: "ignacio1:e606c4b40ddd9c0353ac275ef7e52ac3-us17",
        
            }
        
            const request = https.request(url, options, function (response) {
        
        
                if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
                } else {
                    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
                }
        
        
                response.on("data", function (data) {
                    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
                })
        
            })
        
            request.write(jsonData);
            request.end();
        

})


app.post("/failure", function(req,res){
    res.redirect("/");
});



app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
    console.log("Example app listening on port 3000!!!");
});
```

Código cliente:

```
// Formulario

const formulario = document.getElementById("myForm");
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#myForm input"); //accedemos a todos los inputs del formulario


const expresiones = {
    nombre: /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\s]{1,40}$/, // Letras y espacios, pueden llevar acentos.
    apellidos: /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\s]{1,40}$/, // Letras y espacios, pueden llevar acentos.
    correo: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/,
    telefono: /^\d{7,14}$/ // 7 a 14 numeros.

}

const campos = {
    nombre: false,
    apellidos: false,
    correo: false,
    telefono: false
}

const validarFormulario = (e) => {

    switch (e.target.name) {
        case "nombre":
            validarCampo(expresiones.nombre, e.target, "nombre");

            break;
        case "apellidos":
            validarCampo(expresiones.apellidos, e.target, "apellidos");

            break;
        case "correo":
            validarCampo(expresiones.correo, e.target, "correo");

            break;
        case "telefono":
            validarCampo(expresiones.telefono, e.target, "telefono");

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}


const validarCampo = (expresion, input, campo) => {
    if (expresion.test(input.value)) {
        document.getElementById(`grupo__${campo}`).classList.add("formulario__grupo-correcto");
        document.getElementById(`grupo__${campo}`).classList.remove("formulario__grupo-incorrecto");
        document.querySelector(`#grupo__${campo} i`).classList.remove("fa-times-circle");
        document.querySelector(`#grupo__${campo} i`).classList.add("fa-check-circle");

        document.querySelector(`#grupo__${campo} .formulario__input-error`).classList.remove("formulario__input-error-activo");

        campos[campo] = true;

    } else {

        document.getElementById(`grupo__${campo}`).classList.add("formulario__grupo-incorrecto");
        document.getElementById(`grupo__${campo}`).classList.remove('formulario__grupo-correcto');
        document.querySelector(`#grupo__${campo} i`).classList.add("fa-times-circle");
        document.querySelector(`#grupo__${campo} i`).classList.remove("fa-check-circle");



        document.querySelector(`#grupo__${campo} .formulario__input-error`).classList.add("formulario__input-error-activo");

        campos[campo] = false;
    }
}


inputs.forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener("keyup", validarFormulario); //en cada input cada vez que levante la tecla se ejecuta la función validarFormulario
    input.addEventListener("blur", validarFormulario); //en cada input cada vez que le de con el ratón fuera de los inputs se ejecute la función validarFormulario

}) // por cada input me ejecutas una función

formulario.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    const terminos = document.getElementById("terminos");


    if (campos.nombre && campos.apellidos && campos.correo && campos.telefono && terminos.checked){

        formulario.reset();

        document.getElementById("formulario__mensaje-exito").classList.add("formulario__mensaje-exito-activo");
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById("formulario__mensaje-exito").classList.remove("formulario__mensaje-exito-activo");
        }, 5000);

        document.querySelectorAll(".formulario__grupo-correcto").forEach((icono) => {
            icono.classList.remove("formulario__grupo-correcto");
        });
       

    } else {

        document.querySelector(".formulario__mensaje-p").classList.add("formulario__mensaje-p-activo");
        setTimeout(()=>{
            document.querySelector(".formulario__mensaje-p").classList.remove("formulario__mensaje-p-activo");

        },5000);


       
    }
})
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende, por favor leer [ask]. Confundes acciones en el cliente con acciones en el servidor. Validas y envías en el cliente, tu servidor (node) recibe los datos, los puedes (debes) volver a validar y enviar a tu servicio de correo. El código debe mostrarse en formato texto, no en imagen. Falta el código de tu servidor de Node para revisar cómo recibes los datos. Y falta el código de tu script en el cliente para ver como *validas* y envías los datos. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Gracias. Soy bastante novato. He editado el mensaje con el código del cliente y el código del servidor.